# TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType' when using cv2

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

# Get the training data we previously made
data_path = 'C:\\Users\\hp\\Unlock-Application\\frames'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(data_path) if isfile(join(data_path, f))]

# Create arrays for training data and labels
Training_Data, Labels = [], []

# Open training images in our datapath
# Create a numpy array for training data
for i, files in enumerate(onlyfiles):
    image_path = data_path + onlyfiles[i]
    images = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    Training_Data.append(np.asarray(images, dtype=np.uint8))
    Labels.append(i)

# Create a numpy array for both training data and labels
Labels = np.asarray(Labels, dtype=np.int32)

# Initialize facial recognizer
model = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()

# NOTE: For OpenCV 3.0 use cv2.face.createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

# Let's train our model 
model.train(np.asarray(Training_Data), np.asarray(Labels))
print(cv2.__version__)
print("Model trained sucessefully")
```

When I run this code I get this error

```
File "c:\Users\hp\Unlock-Application\model.py", line 18, in <module>
Training_Data.append(np.asarray(images, dtype=np.uint8))
```

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
any guess how to solve this?

Comment: Please post the **full** error message

Comment: also something that we can run, I cannot possibly guess what you have in your frame directory

Comment: There's no call to `int()` anywhere in this code. We need the full traceback to see which library function is getting the error.

Comment: I suspect `images` is `None`.  `cv2` returns this when it can't read the file.

Comment: The [imread doc](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga288b8b3da0892bd651fce07b3bbd3a56) is vague about what the return value is for the python binding. You could run the script in a terminal with the "-i" option so that it brings up the python shell on the error. Then you could take a peek at what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error originates from this line:

`onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(data_path) if isfile(join(data_path, f))]`

You are checking if `isfile` but instead you should be checking if it's an image i.e if its `.png`, `.jpg`, because anything can be a file. The string method `endswith()` can be used for this.

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(data_path) if isfile(join(data_path, f))]

```
for f in listdir(data_path):
    image_path = os.path.join(data_path, f) 
    if image_path.endswith(('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg')): # you can add other formats
       images = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```